# How to implement vertical tabs cocoa app

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I want to achieve something like this:
[image: tab one]

[image: tab two]

the left side is the tab list or menu list, and the right side is the detail page of this tab. When I select one of the tab, then the content on the right side will change. Since the contents of tabs are totally different, so I think maybe I should use different ViewControllers for different right-side pages, and something like a root controller for the tabs. But I don't know how exactly the app architecture should be, I want to have a simple example of that (maybe something like:
-TabController
-TabOneDetailViewController
-TabTwoDetailViewController)
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In macOS this is named sidebar and not vertical tabs. There is an older sample code from Apple which shows you exactly how it should be implemented. https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/SidebarDemo/Introduction/Intro.html
To simplify it if you don't need the NSOutlineView functionality you could use NSTableView instead.

Have fun.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot : )